# Why do my HTML elements inherit the parent elements opacity

Tags: html, css

So i placed an image tag in my HTML doc and it seemed to inherit the opacity from the parent div element. I have tried many methods to change this but it will not work.
An example:

```
<div style="opacity: 0.7">
<img src="http://parteetime.com/pics/wallpaper/majestic-1280-1024.jpg"/> 
</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: It's in the element. It's only natural that if an element is semitransparent, so is everything inside it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`opacity` makes whole element opaque.

Use rgba as background-color to prevent whole element from being opaque.

This will only make translucent background.

Try:

```
div{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);} //rgba -- red,green,blue,alpha
```

[See fiddle for the difference,](http://jsfiddle.net/9a7mZ/)